# I've just installed php on CentOS but need to integrate with Apache

Tags: php, apache-2.2, httpd.conf

Through yum, rpm commands I've got php53  and other 53 versions common pdo cli mysql pdo

I can't tell what version of apache I have, or how to integrate this php into apache.

```
[root@server1 httpd]# yum list installed | grep 'apache'
```

vzdummy-apache.noarch               1.0-1.swsoft                       installed

Am I on Apache 1.x or 2.x  ?
Will I need to update or compile Apache from source, to compile PHP module in it ?
or can I use DSO ? 
  Build and Install Apache (with DSO support)

I've found my configuration files, for apache and php 
and I can do which php  ( and it shows   /usr/bin/php  ) 
  but I'm not sure, any other directories that are used, or where php.ini-recommended is ??

Ah, using

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | grep Configuration
```

I see that my php.ini   is located at   /etc/php.ini

Also reading through the httpd.conf, I'm guessing I'm on 1.2, with this text

```
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/> for
// and I see this also - Including the php configuration files
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

And my php.conf  has the `AddHandler`  directives. 
I would next need to track down the modules that are referenced, to confirm they exist.

I've also reviewed my logs  ( access and error ) and can't find anything terribly wrong;  It just seems that Apache will ignore any requests for a .php resource.

Suggestions welcome;  I must be missing something silly.  TIA, for your help.

Comment: On CentOS 5.2 and I did restart Apache, also.

Answer (score 0):

on centos rhel and so on, apache normaly is named as httpd check yum list installed | grep 'httpd'

Answer (score 0):

> vzdummy-apache.noarch 1.0-1.swsoft
>   installed

Apache package is named `httpd`. I don't know what this vzdummy is. This is not from any standard repository. I suggest you remove both httpd and php by

```
yum -y remove httpd
yum -y remove php\*
```

and after that reinstall from scratch:

```
yum install httpd
yum install php php-XXX php-YYY
```

where php-XXX and php-YYY packages for PHP you need.

Execute

```
updatedb
```

Then execute

```
locate *.repo
```

to see if you have any third-party repositories on your CentOS. You should have the output like this:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Testing.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo
```

If you have something else, new repositories can clash with standard ones preventing your OS from working correctly. You have to [setup priorities](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities) for all packages.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.  Thru the help of IRC chat ( #bind, #centOS ) 
I was able to find out that I probably had a fake CentOS version created with openvz

I did use yum update ( rpm ) to update the whole box to CentOS 5.6 and things got working.